# The integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the integral inequality $I(a, b) \ge ab$, where: $I(a, b) = \int_0^a f(x)dx + \int_0^b {f}^{-1}(y)dy$, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and continuous on the interval $[0; +\infty)$, $f(0) = 0$, and $a, b \ge 0$.

Comment: Is $f^{-1}$ the inverse function of $f$? or simply its reciprocal?

Comment: inverse function, I apologize, forgot to clarify.

Comment: [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions)

Comment: Draw the right picture and it's head-slap obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f^{-1}(b) \leq a$. Then 
$$\int_0^{a} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy = \int _{f^{-1}(b)}^a f(x)dx + \int_0^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy$$
$$=\int _{f^{-1}(b)}^a (f(x)- b + b) dx + \int_0^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy$$
$$=\int _{f^{-1}(b)}^a (f(x)- b)dx + \int _{f^{-1}(b)}^a b dx + \int_0^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy$$
$$=A + (ba-bf^{-1}(b)) + \int_0^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy$$
for some $A \geq 0.$
$$\geq ba + \int_0^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy -bf^{-1}(b)$$
So show that 
$$\int_0^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy -bf^{-1}(b) =0$$
That is,
$$
\int_0^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_0^{b} f^{-1} (y) dy =bf^{-1}(b)$$
$$ = \int_{x=0}^{x=f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_{y=0}^{y=b} f^{-1} (y) dy =bf^{-1}(b)$$
Now note that $x=0 \iff y=0$, and $x=f^{-1}(b) \iff y=b,$ and also that 
$$f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(f(x)) = x,$$ 
and 
$$dy = \frac{dy}{dx}dx = f'(x)dx.$$
so making these substitutions yields:
$$ = \int_{x=0}^{x=f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + \int_{x=0}^{x=f^{-1}(b)} x f'(x)dx =bf^{-1}(b)$$
Integrate by parts on the second term:
$$ = \int_{x=0}^{x=f^{-1}(b)} f(x)dx + xf\Big |_{0}^{f^{-1}(b)} -\int_{x=0}^{x=f^{-1}(b)} f(x) dx =bf^{-1}(b)$$
$$bf^{-1}(b) =bf^{-1}(b)$$
As desired.